# How to use setAttribute to an element in code with {}?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

How can I attribute such code to a html tag?

It's a attr ===>>>   `data-kt-drawer-activate="{default: true, lg: false}"`

I tried the following method but I get an error:

```
newAside.setAttribute("data-kt-drawer-activate", "{default: true, lg: false}" );
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: What error are you getting? It works for me

Comment: is working https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlgZZ.jpg, maybe is because your element is undefined... are you tried to `console.log(newAside)`

Comment: Syntax Error in template "/srv/www/vhosts/projects/data/invoicing/templates/Overview.tpl" on line 66 "newAside.setAttribute(&quot;data-kt-drawer-activate&quot;, &quot;{default: true, lg: false}&quot; );" - Unexpected ": ", expected one of: "}" , " "

#0 /smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:3154 Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error()
#1 /smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:3219 Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_syntax_error(2,': ')

Comment: You should post all relevant code; seems like your `SmartyPlugins` is pretty pertinent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this current page, I ran your code as below:

```
let newAside= document.querySelector("#question > div > div.postcell.post-layout--right > div.mb0 > div")
    newAside.setAttribute("data-kt-drawer-activate", "{default: true, lg: false}" );
console.log(newAside)

output: <div class="mt16 d-flex gs8 gsy fw-wrap jc-end ai-start pt4 mb16" data-kt-drawer-activate="{default: true, lg: false}">...
```

so setting attribute part of your code works. I think problem occurs when you are selecting the element